# ASP.NET Collapsable navbar remember closed or not

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a asp.net .net framework web forms project.

I have a collapsable side-navbar

```
$("#sidebarToggle, #sidebarToggleTop").on('click', function(e) {
    $("body").toggleClass("sidebar-toggled");
    $(".sidebar").toggleClass("toggled");
    if ($(".sidebar").hasClass("toggled")) {
       $('.sidebar .collapse').collapse('hide');
    };
});
```

this is the function that I use to collapse or make the navbar bigger. 
now I want to make this be remembered in like a cookie or such so it saves the fact or it is collapsed or not

Edit: Current code

```
 var isCollapsed = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Document is ready');
        if (localStorage.getItem('navbarstatus') != null) {
            isCollapsed = localStorage.getItem('navbarstatus');
            console.log(isCollapsed);
        }

        $("#sidebarToggle, #sidebarToggleTop").on('click', function (e) {
            console.log("Before: " + isCollapsed);
            isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;
            localStorage.setItem('navbarstatus', isCollapsed);
            console.log('After: ' + isCollapsed);
            $("body").toggleClass("sidebar-toggled");
            $(".sidebar").toggleClass("toggled");
            if ($(".sidebar").hasClass("toggled")) {
                $('.sidebar .collapse').collapse('hide');
            };
        });

    });
Debug:

Before: false
After: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you can have a flag e.g. `isCollapsed` and

```
var isCollapsed = "false"
```

set it's value in Collapse function i.e.

```
isCollapsed = "true"; //or "false"
```

Next you can save this value in browser localStorage or webStorage i.e.

```
localStorage.setItem('navbarstatus', isCollapsed);
```

Now you can check and retrieve navbar *collapsed status* by fetching value from local storage:

```
$(document).ready(function) {
if(localStorage.getItem('navbarstatus')) {
isCollapsed = localStorage.getItem('navbarstatus')
//do what you want to do next, you have Collapsed information  about navbar

}

});
```

you can use 'localStorage' or 'webStorage' based on your requirements.
Hope this helps.

**Edit :**

In you click handler:

```
 console.log ("Before: " + isCollapsed);
            if(isCollapsed == "true") 
            isCollapsed = "false";
            else
            isCollapsed = "true";

            localStorage.setItem('navbarstatus', isCollapsed);

            console.log('After: ' + isCollapsed);
```

Comment: I've been trying to recreate this in a functional way but it seems the first time I press my button it won't work

Comment: if you could post the code, this would help identifying the problem.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit. The problem is that when I first press the button the isCollapsed doesn't change.

Comment: try creating a global variable `var isCollapsed = false` before `$(document).ready`

Comment: this inconsistency is due to bool to string conversion issue when you retrieve this from local stroage. for simplicity you can initialize `isCollapsed` as string and use that value further. check the updated answer